# Jmeter - Non HTTP response message: handshake alert: unrecognized_name

Tags: jmeter

```
Jmeter 3.0
jdk1.8.0_92
jre1.8.0_92
```

Getting Error while executing Script:-

```
Response message: Embedded resource download    
error:https://xxxx.xxxxx.com/search?client=special_srch_frontend code:Non HTTP response code: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException message:Non HTTP response message: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name,
```

When I execute script with SNI - False, then above Passes But other redirections (302) fails.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try running jmeter with this additional java system property:

> -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false

Comment: Yes I am running Jmeter Scripts with -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false. While running some request working fine. But some are fail and give SSL Hanshake error.

Comment: After SNI disabled, getting error for those request which have embedded resources related with different domain.                    Read SNI document,                                     but not able to understand that how we can disable or enable -"Djsse.enableSNIExtension" on Runtime for a specific http request.

Comment: could yougive the full details of error when you set this option and when you don't set it ? show jmeter.log

Comment: When using -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false then getting 403 <html> <head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head> <body bgcolor="white"> <center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center> <hr><center>cloudflare-nginx</center> </body> </html> <!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page --> –

Comment: Also, oktapreview 302 pass when -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false but previously it was fail with jmeter.bat

Comment: Also Please see the full Error above, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

when not use with `-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false` and start jmeter with jmeter.bat, then getting error as:-

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: handshake alert:  unrecognized_name
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.handshakeAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jmeter.util.SlowOutputStream.write(SlowOutputStream.java:47)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.flushRequestOutputStream(HttpConnection.java:828)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.writeRequest(HttpMethodBase.java:2116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1096)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl.sample(HTTPHC3Impl.java:269)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1958)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase$ASyncSample.call(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1926)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please help on this

Comment: I am still facing the Same issue. Anyone Please Help me on this