# Jmeter SNI Issue

Tags: jmeter

```
JMeter 3.0 

Java 8
```

Getting SNI issue while redirect 302 requests. When running JMeter script with

```
java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false
```

it fails. When make

```
java -Djsse.enableSNIExtension=True
```

it Passes.

But further HTTP request fails. How we can solve this. Do I set

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
```

run time when Jmeter Script running?. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jmeter - Non HTTP response message: handshake alert: unrecognized\_name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706221/jmeter-non-http-response-message-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name)

Comment: Do you have some public site exposing the problem ? Note that you already asked this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38706221/jmeter-non-http-response-message-handshake-alert-unrecognized-name/38707164#38707164 , unless you provide more information it will be hard to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Put a [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) at the beginning of the Thread group, and set the following script:

```
System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");
```

**It must be defined before any HTTP Sampler**, otherwise the setting won't be taken into account. See [JSR223 Samples](https://doc.octoperf.com/virtual-user/jsr223-samples/#configuration-change) for more sample JSR223 scripts.

[image: JMeter JSR223 Disable SNI]

For Further information, see [Fix JMeter SNI Issue](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/12/07/fix-jmeter-sni-issue/).